# Move tab to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I want to put a + icon and a pen icon below the app, look similar with image below. What are the name for the grey color widget? Is it called `tabHost` ? From what I understood, it is used for tab Layout with Swipeable Views?

[image]

Anyone?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </FrameLayout>
         <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: @John Joe visit this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 1):

Use FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```